# Is there a easy way to check for free internal or external Memory?

Tags: flutter

I want to check for free available storage before audio Recorder is started in my Flutter audio recorder app.

So is there a built-in way to check it?

Another option would be to create a plugin and use platform-specific code.

Comment: Try this worked for me. May work for you too!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59613682/11298901

Answer (score 1):

Use [storage_info 0.0.1](https://pub.dev/packages/storage_info) plugin

Using this plugin you can access Internal and External Storage Space

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such build-in method in Flutter right now. Flutter would rely on native platforms to get the current memory status of the device. You could try to implement a plugin yourself.