# Flutter: Check Device Available Storage using Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

How to check device storage is it possible to do it in Flutter without doing natively? I want to know if the device has enough storage to download images. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a package called [disk_space](https://pub.dev/packages/disk_space) that allows you to get exactly the information you are looking for. You can use it like this:

```dart
import 'package:disk_space/disk_space.dart';

void getDiskSpaceInfo() async{
  print(await DiskSpace.getFreeDiskSpace);
  print(await DiskSpace.getTotalDiskSpace);
}
```

*EDIT: This package has been updated to version 0.1.0+2 for Dart 2.12 on Mar 9, 2021. But still has no link to GitHub.*

Comment: I've tested it on iOS and Android and it works in both. If an answer solves your issue, please mark it as correct

Comment: @RodrigoHenriques The documentation doesn't state, but I believe it is bytes, yes.

Comment: @JoãoSoares after double checking the source code I saw that the value is in megabytes. If you look at the plugin native code you can see for yourself.

Comment: @JoãoSoares I would like to ask, did you know that ```DiskSpace.getTotalDiskSpace```  was accessing internal storage only or with sd card storage?... I try to implement it to my project, but I get different result when comparing with space in my phone

Comment: @uyhaW Sorry, I am not aware of the actual implementation. I haven't been able to find the GitHub page of that package, and it also hasn't been updated since November 2019.

Comment: @JoãoSoares thank you very much for your information

Comment: disk space is not returning correct size.

Answer (score 4):

One of the possibilities is to use already mentioned `DiskSpace` with a bit of a change.

### The library contains two files:

`disk_space.dart`:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class DiskSpace {
  static const MethodChannel _channel =
      const MethodChannel('disk_space');

  static Future<String?> get platformVersion async {
    final String? version = await _channel.invokeMethod('getPlatformVersion');
    return version;
  }

  static Future<double?> get getFreeDiskSpace async {
    final double? freeDiskSpace = await _channel.invokeMethod('getFreeDiskSpace');
    return freeDiskSpace;
  }

  static Future<double?> get getTotalDiskSpace async {
    final double? totalDiskSpace = await _channel.invokeMethod('getTotalDiskSpace');
    return totalDiskSpace;
  }
}
```

and

`DiskSpacePlugin.kt`:

```kotlin
package de.appgewaltig.disk_space

import android.os.Environment
import android.os.StatFs
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.Registrar

class DiskSpacePlugin: MethodCallHandler {
  companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun registerWith(registrar: Registrar) {
      val channel = MethodChannel(registrar.messenger(), "disk_space")
      channel.setMethodCallHandler(DiskSpacePlugin())
    }
  }

  private fun getFreeDiskSpace(): Double {
    val stat = StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path)

    var bytesAvailable: Long

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
      bytesAvailable = stat.blockSizeLong * stat.availableBlocksLong
    else
      bytesAvailable = stat.blockSize.toLong() * stat.availableBlocks.toLong()
    return (bytesAvailable / (1024f * 1024f)).toDouble()
  }

  private fun getTotalDiskSpace(): Double {
    val stat = StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path)

    var bytesAvailable: Long

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
      bytesAvailable = stat.blockSizeLong * stat.blockCountLong
    else
      bytesAvailable = stat.blockSize.toLong() * stat.blockCount.toLong()
    return (bytesAvailable / (1024f * 1024f)).toDouble()
  }


  override fun onMethodCall(call: MethodCall, result: Result) {
    when(call.method) {
      "getFreeDiskSpace" -> result.success(getFreeDiskSpace())
      "getTotalDiskSpace" -> result.success(getTotalDiskSpace())
      else -> result.notImplemented()
    }
  }
}
```

---

### My changes:

I've added another channel method (and a method to the KT file to get internal storage):

```kotlin
class DiskSpacePlugin: MethodCallHandler {
  ...

  private fun getFreeDiskSpace(String path): Double {
    val stat = StatFs(path) // dynamic path from the Flutter

    var bytesAvailable: Long

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
      bytesAvailable = stat.blockSizeLong * stat.availableBlocksLong
    else
      bytesAvailable = stat.blockSize.toLong() * stat.availableBlocks.toLong()
    return (bytesAvailable / (1024f * 1024f)).toDouble()
  }

  private fun getFreeInternalDiskSpace(): Double {
    val stat = StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().path) // changed to get internal directory
    ...
  }

  private fun getFreeExternalDiskSpace(): Double {...} // Changed name to reflect external directory

  private fun getTotalDiskSpace(): Double {...}


  override fun onMethodCall(call: MethodCall, result: Result) {
    when(call.method) {
      "getFreeDiskSpace" -> {
        var path = call.argument("path") as String
        result.success(getFreeDiskSpace(path)) // added this
      }
      "getFreeInternalDiskSpace" -> result.success(getFreeInternalDiskSpace())
      "getFreeExternalDiskSpace" -> result.success(getFreeExternalDiskSpace())
      "getTotalDiskSpace" -> result.success(getTotalDiskSpace())
      else -> result.notImplemented()
    }
  }
}
```

Registered the Plugin in the `FlutterActivity`:

```java
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);

    DiskSpacePlugin.registerWith(registrarFor("<your_package>.DiskSpacePlugin"));
  }
}
```

Added a `Storage` helper:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class Storage {
  static Future<Directory> internal() async {
    return getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  }
  
  static Future<Directory> external() async {
    return getExternalStorageDirectory();
  }

  static Future<Directory> sdCard() async {
    return (await getExternalStorageDirectories()).firstWhere(
      (directory) => !directory.path.contains("emulated"),
      orElse: () => null,
    );
  }
}
```

And now you can call these from the dart code:

```dart
static const MethodChannel _channel = const MethodChannel('disk_space');

void getFreeMemory() async {
  final String internal = (await Storage.internal()).path;
  final String external = (await Storage.external()).path;
  final String sdCard = (await Storage.sdCard()).path;

  final double freeDiskSpace = await _channel.invokeMethod('getFreeDiskSpace', {"path": internal});
  final double freeExternalDiskSpace = await _channel.invokeMethod('getFreeDiskSpace', {"path": external});
  if (sdCard != null) {
    final double freeSdCardSpace = await _channel.invokeMethod('getFreeDiskSpace', {"path": sdCard});
  }
}
```

---

PS: If someone has a contact to the DiskSpace lib developer - what if ask him to add something mentioned to the library? thx

Comment: This looks awesome @NonGrate! Does this code work to get the disk space for MacOS, Windows and Linux too please?

Comment: I haven't tested that. If someone can - I would be grateful.

Comment: Hi @0xba1, you need to add that .kt file to the android directory (as if you would add the file to the android project - android/app/src/main/java/.../...)

Answer (score 0):

The test is to expand the storage space

```html
  private fun getFreeDiskSpace(): Double {
    val stat = StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path)

    var bytesAvailable: Long

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
      bytesAvailable = stat.blockSizeLong * stat.availableBlocksLong
    else
      bytesAvailable = stat.blockSize.toLong() * stat.availableBlocks.toLong()
    return (bytesAvailable / (1024f * 1024f)).toDouble()
  }

  private fun getTotalDiskSpace(): Double {
    val stat = StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path)

    var bytesAvailable: Long

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
      bytesAvailable = stat.blockSizeLong * stat.blockCountLong
    else
      bytesAvailable = stat.blockSize.toLong() * stat.blockCount.toLong()
    return (bytesAvailable / (1024f * 1024f)).toDouble()
  }
```

Comment: The original post is for Flutter and not Android.