# Is there a way to find device total and free storage information?`

Tags: flutter

I need to find the device total free and used space. I used disk_space: ^0.2.1 package but I am not getting close to accurate value. Anyone can help on this topic?

Comment: You can get more info on the below link. [Answer Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59613682/10135062)

Comment: in this link kt file has been modified but I do not know how I tried bunch of other packages but still could not get near value of my total space of mobile phone